# Azure Data Factory: How to rename blob csv or text file in blob storage during copy or import?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-sql-database

I have some csv file name "Hist_Firms202006221017.csv" in my local machine.
I need to upload it in Azure BLOB with new name "Hist_Firms".
Basically i need to trim the timestamp part in copy data of azure Pipeline.
Can someone help me with example and screen shot.

Comment: which way did you use to upload the file? You add these so many tags which confused us!

Comment: Usually, we using get metadata active to get the source file name,  set a sink dataset  parameter with filename. Then build an expression to set the new output file name.

Comment: can you please help me through some example link. I am new to the azure functionality.

Comment: Sure, I will show you the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could reference my steps. My file is in blob storage with the same "Hist_Firms202006221017":
[image]

**1. Using [Get Metadata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-get-metadata-activity) to get the file name:**
[image]

**2. In copy active, the same source with Get Metadata:**
[image]

**3. Copy active Sink dataset settings, add a parameter "filename":**
[image]

**4. Copy active Sink settings: using expression to build the new file name "Hist_Firms":**

```
@concat(substring(activity('Get Metadata1').output.itemname,0,10),'.csv')
```

[image]

**5. Run the pipeline:**
[image]

**6. File check:**
[image]

The difference is my source dataset is in Blob Storage, please change to your file location.

Hope this helps.

Comment: how to handle file names if the name of the file is not fix. Only we have to remove the date part from the file name? Let's take an example of these two file name "Hist_Firms202006221017.csv" & "Hist_New202006221017.csv".So in BLOB file name should be Hist_Firm & Hist_New. I checked the string optoins like REVERSE(), Charindex these are not supportive one. Please help with example.

Comment: Hi @swad, I know your meaning. Can you post another question? Just change the  expression could achieve it.

Comment: If all the filename is end with '.csv', you could use this expression `@substring(activity('Get Metadata1').output.itemname,0,add(length(activity('Get Metadata1').output.itemname),-16))`,I tested and it works well.